# I'm trying to understand the recursion process?

Tags: python, recursion

```
houses = ["Shaah's house", "Joseph's house", "Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]

def deliver_presents_recursively(houses):
    # Worker elf doing his work
    if len(houses) == 1:
        house = houses[0]
        print("Delivering presents to", house)
    else:
        mid = len(houses) // 2
        first_half = houses[:mid]
        second_half = houses[mid:]

        # Divides his work among two elves
        deliver_presents_recursively(first_half)
        deliver_presents_recursively(second_half)
```

> > > deliver_presents_recursively(houses)

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is can be tough to understand, but it works like magic.

In your example, `deliver_presents_recursively` has the task to deliver presents to each house provided. How? Well, clearly one can deliver presents to only one house at a time, so `deliver_presents_recursively` attempts to simplify the problem.

If provided only one house (`if len(houses) == 1:`), `deliver_presents_recursively` delivers the present and exits (well, returns to the calling function, actually).

If provided more than one house, it divides the list in half and then attempts to deliver to the first half & then the second half. Since `deliver_presents_recursively` takes any number of houses, you can re-use that function to attempt to deliver these two smaller groups of houses.

Recursion requires a call to itself, which you have, usually with a reduced parameter set, which you do (that is, you don't want to call the function with the same parameters as otherwise it will never end!)

Recursion also requires a terminator, such as your `len(houses) == 1`. That is, a case where it will **not** call itself again.

In this particular case, it would probably make sense to use simple iteration like:

```
def deliver_presents_non_recursively(houses):
    for house in houses:
        print ("Delivering presents to", house)
```

but then you're not experimenting with recursion.

Another simple recursion example is factorial (8! equals 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 ...). Think of it this way:

```
What is 8 factorial? 
- it's 8 * 7 factorial
  What is 7 factorial?
  - it's 7 * 6 factorial
    What is 6 factorial?
    - it's 6 * 5 factorial
      What is 5 factorial?
      - it's 5 * 4 factorial
        What is 4 factorial?
        - it's 4 * 3 factorial
          What is 3 factorial?
          - it's 3 * 2 factorial
            What is 2 factorial?
            - it's 2 * 1 factorial
              What is 1 factorial?
              - it's 1
              therefore 2 * 1
            therefore 3 * 2
          therefore 4 * 6
        therefore 5 * 24
      therefore 6 * 120
    therefore 7 * 720
  therefore 8 * 5040
therefore 40320
```

See how each instance is "smaller" than the previous, until it reaches a termination point (1 factorial) and then the results percolate back up.